# Can't add header to the MFC ListControl

Tags: c++, mfc, clistctrl

I'm writing a simple MFC application,which uses a ListControl, but I can't get it to write the header data in it in the OnInitDialog function.
Here's what I tried:

```
   lvColumn.mask = LVCF_FMT | LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_WIDTH; 
   lvColumn.fmt = LVCFMT_LEFT;
   lvColumn.cx = 120;
   lvColumn.pszText = _T("ID");
   m_listCtrl.InsertColumn(0, &lvColumn);
```

When the window appears it doesn't give an error, but it's not working either.

Comment: Remarks for [`ListView_InsertColumn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775032.aspx): *"Columns are visible only in report (details) view."*

Comment: Added `m_listCtrl.SetExtendedStyle(LVS_REPORT);` this line. Still not visible.

Comment: `LVS_REPORT` is not an [Extended List-View Style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774732.aspx). You need to to specify it when creating the control.